# Which is the best way to implement a sparse vector in Java?

Tags: java, sparse-array

Which is the best way to implement a sparse vector in Java?

Of course the good thing would be to have something that can be manipulated quite easily (normalization, scalar product and so on)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MTJ](https://github.com/fommil/matrix-toolkits-java) has a [Sparse Vector](http://static.javadoc.io/com.googlecode.matrix-toolkits-java/mtj/1.0.4/no/uib/cipr/matrix/sparse/SparseVector.html) class.  It has norm functions (1-norm 2-norm and ∞-norm) and dot product functions.

Answer (score 3):

[JScience](http://jscience.org/) has a [SparseVector](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/vector/SparseVector.html) implementation that is part of its [linear algebra](http://jscience.org/api/index.html) package.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try to look at [la4j](http://la4j.org)'s [CompressedVector](https://github.com/vkostyukov/la4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/la4j/vector/sparse/CompressedVector.java) implementation. It uses pair of arrays: array of values and array of their indicies. And with binary search on top of that it just flies. So, this implementation guarantees `O(log n)` running time for `get`/`set` operations.

Just a brief example

```
Vector a = new CompressedVector(new double[]{ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 }).

// calculates L_1 norm of the vector
double n = a.norm();

// calculates the sum of vectors elements
double s = a.fold(Vectors.asSumAccumulator(0.0));
```